# Join multiple tables from multiple databases

Tags: sql, powershell

I was able to run a query against one table from a database. Now I am trying to add a second database to my connection string to be able to make join but getting error messages. I couldn't find any syntax for `$connectionString` to add multiple connections.

Part of my code:

```bsh
$connectionString = “DSN=MyServer;Uid=MyAccID;Pwd=MyPWD;DSN=MyServer2;Uid=MyAccID;Pwd=MyPWD;”
$connection = New-Object System.Data.Odbc.DdbcConnection
$connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString
$connection.Open()

$query = “SELECT PersonID, LastName FROM jdeprod.dbo.Persons LEFT JOIN proddta.f0101 on LastName = abalph”

$command = $connection.CreateCommand()
$command.CommandText = $query
```

Comment: You might find some useful information from various links from [this Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=odbc+connection+to+multiple+databases)...

Comment: do not mention the db name in the connection string . Mention the DBServer,UId and pwd and connect. access withe dbname.schemaname.table name. In this way, you can join both the databases if you have permission. Other method includes adding it under system dsn.

Comment: Thank you Ranadip Dutta. But my databases are on different servers. :/

Comment: Edit your question and add these information please, be more detailed.

Comment: You cannot connect to multiple databases with one connection unless you have a "frontend" database with some kind of federation mechanism to integrate multiple backend databases. How that works depends on what DBMS you're using. Otherwise you'll have to fetch the data and merge them on the application side.